# find two primes less than $500$ that divide $20^{22}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, divisibility

> Find two primes less than $500$ that divide $20^{22}+1$.

Note that $20^2+1=401$ divides the required number (since for any integer a, if k is odd, then $a+1$ divides $a^k+1$). Also, any prime dividing the given number must be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ since $-1$ would be a quadratic residue modulo any such prime. Primes like $17$ and $13$ don't work. $20\equiv 7\mod 13, 20\equiv 3\mod 17,$ and in both cases $20$ is a primitive root with respect to the corresponding modulus. So it might be that we'll need to find a large prime. $a^k+1 = (a+1)(a^{(k-1)} - a^{(k-2)}+\cdots + 1),$ where $a = 20^2, k=11.$  I'm not sure if there's some way to factor $a^{(k-1)} -a^{(k-2)}+\cdots + 1.$

Comment: $ p \neq 2,5,$   $20^{p-1}  \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose a prime $p$ (necessarily odd) divides $20^{22} + 1$. Then $20^{22} \equiv -1 \bmod p$ so $20^{44} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and it follows that the order of $20 \bmod p$ divides $44$ but does not divide $22$. This means it must be divisible by $4$, so must be either $4$ or $44$. If $20^4 \equiv 1 \bmod p$ then $20^{22} \equiv 20^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$ so we conclude that $p \mid 401$ and hence $p = 401$. Otherwise the order of $20 \bmod p$ is $44$, from which it follows that $p \equiv 1 \bmod 44$.

The smallest such prime is $p = 89$, and we have

$$\begin{align*} 20^{22} &= 400^{11} \equiv 44^{11} \\
 & \equiv \left( \frac{89 - 1}{2} \right)^{11}  \equiv \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right)^{11} \\
 & \equiv - \frac{1}{32 \cdot 64} \equiv \frac{1}{32 \cdot 25} \\
 & \equiv \frac{1}{800} \equiv - \frac{1}{90} \\
 & \equiv - 1 \bmod 89 \end{align*} $$

so $p = 89$ works. This is a slightly annoying computation, though, so I don't know if it was what was intended. There were only three primes to check, namely $p = 89, 353, 397$ although if $89$ hadn't worked generating the rest of this list would've been slightly annoying and checking it would've been slightly annoying too, I think.

Comment: I wolframmed it and apparently the prime factorization is $20^{22}+1\equiv 89\cdot 401\cdot 170770770413\cdot 6881957521693$

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at [this linear algebra problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537136/prove-that-there-exists-a-basis-so-that-l-a-is-diagonal) if you have time?

Comment: +1 The computations are a lot less annoying with the two observations
\begin{eqnarray}
5^3&\equiv&125&\equiv&36&\equiv&6^2&\pmod{89},\\ 
5^4&\equiv&5\times36&\equiv&180&\equiv&2&\pmod{89},
\end{eqnarray}
as this shows that $5$ is a quadratic residue and so $2$ is an eighth power. Then you quickly get
$$20^{22}\equiv2^{44}5^{22}\equiv5^{22}\equiv2^55^2\equiv32\times25\equiv800\pmod{89}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I claim that the two primes are $89$ and $401$. The $401$ is kind of obvious because $20^{22}=(20^2)^{11}\equiv (-1)^{11}\equiv -1\pmod{401}$. The $89$ is a bit more subtle. Note that $2^{44}\pmod{89}$ is just $\left(\frac{2}{89}\right)$, the Legendre symbol. It's easy to calculate by quadratic reciprocity that this is $1$. I'm too lazy to compute $5^{22}\pmod{89}$ the smart way, so just reduce: $5^{22}\equiv 5\cdot 125^7\equiv 5\cdot 36^7\equiv 5\cdot 36\cdot 1296^3\equiv 2\cdot 50^3\equiv -1\pmod{89}$. Then $20^{22}\equiv 5^{22}\cdot 2^{44}\equiv -1\pmod{89}$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you take a look at [this linear algebra problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537136/prove-that-there-exists-a-basis-so-that-l-a-is-diagonal) if you have time?